# keyboard writes backwards sometimes

Tags: keyboard

I have been using my keyboard for forever and all of a sudden it had this weird thing. sometimes it starts writing backwards while typing. it freezes writing for a while, when i stop pushing the keys it writes them all in reverse order. i think it may be a virus but the scans didn't show anything. do you have any ideas why this may happen? thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you try with another keyboard? Did you reinstall drivers? Did you check if the backspace button is not stuck by something... sticky! lol

Comment: The reason i did not do these is sometimes the keyboard works perfectly fine. For example now it works, but did not work ten minutes ago. Thats why i thought maybe it is a virus, activated by a program maybe so wondered if anyone have been infected by something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a "right to left" language installed?

It could be that you are hitting the key combination that activates it.